# How to save generated pdf with JasperReports API into server

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to save my generated *PDF* file into my server. I am using *JasperReports API*.

Code sample for *PDF* generation:

```java
//Result set(rs)
//Report path (rptPath)
//Hash map (hmp)
//ServletOutputStream (sos)
//HttpServletResponse (resp)

JRResultSetDataSource jrrs = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);
bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(rptPath, hmp, jrrs);
sos = resp.getOutputStream();
resp.setContentType("application/pdf");

resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="MyFile.pdf");

sos.write(bytes);

sos.flush();
sos.close();
```

It directly generates the file and ask for download. Where I want to store the generated file into server.

Comment: My above code is generating a pdf file.I need to save this file into server.It should not ask for download the file.

Comment: So write the file to disk using Java IO capabilities... I do not really understand your problem.

Comment: The generated file should not ask for download.It should saved internally into my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write bytes to the local file on server instead of writing it back to HttpResponse for that.
Your code can look like :

```
FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\report.pdf");
fileOuputStream.write(bytes);
fileOuputStream.close();
```

Comment: Thanks mate.But, you are writing the file here.But, I need to store that same file into server. No need to ask for download, internally i need to save that file.

Comment: Does not this code get executed on server itself ? If yes then the file write will happen local that is server itself right ?

Comment: Yes you are right , but, is there any other way to save that file directly into server ?

Comment: You can may be use runReportToPdfFile(http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperRunManager.html#runToPdfFile(java.lang.String, java.util.Map)) API  http://www.ensode.net/jasperreports_database_pg3.html