# Getting JasperReports generated pdf to display on Browser with Struts2 framework

Tags: java, pdf, struts2, jasper-reports

I am using the Jasper Reports framework along with my Struts2 web app . It was only sometime back that I realised **JasperViewer** wouldn't help me ***display and download*** my report in the Client browser. I saw up a few links and almost all told me to use Servlets and OutputStreams to do this.I tried [this](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/how-to-get-the-httpservletresponse-in-struts-2/) link for getting the Servelet request and response to my Java class. I am quite **new** to this ,so various attempts of using code to do so from these sources [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178748/how-to-save-generated-pdf-with-jasperreports-api-into-server) etc didn't work. This is why I am posting this for help.

The relevant code for my Action class method is

```
public String execute() throws Exception //the method which will be executed
{
                ...
                request=ServletActionContext.getRequest();
                response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
                if(response!=null)
                    System.out.println("Response is not null");
                System.out.println("coming to this method");
                java.io.InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/ram/report/jasper/Report.jrxml");
                JasperReport jasperReport=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(in);
                HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();             
                JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
                JRPdfExporter pdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();
                List<JasperPrint> jasperPrintList= new ArrayList<JasperPrint>(); 
                jasperPrintList.add(jasperPrint);
                pdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST,jasperPrintList);
                pdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME ,request.getRealPath("")+"/Report.pdf");
                pdfExporter.exportReport();

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "ajaxReturn";
        }
        }
            return "success";
    }
```

My action (from which struts.xml is linked to)

```
<action name="reportData" class="Reportfetchnew">
        <interceptor-ref name="cookie"></interceptor-ref>
         <interceptor-ref name="cookieProvider"></interceptor-ref>
         <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success">htdocs/jsp/report_new/report_tool.jsp</result>
         <result name="ajaxReturn" type="stream" >
            <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
            <param name="inputName">in</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>

            </result>

        </action>
```

I am getting this error

```
Exception occurred during processing request: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputStream] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputStream] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.
```

The problem was that before this, when I viewed my Jasper file using JasperViewer, it was working fine.
What should I do to workaround this error **and** get my pdf available to download ?

Comment: Use search -> how to download file in S2. Or even -> how to use jasper report in S2.

Comment: @AleksandrM I managed to get rid of the error and used an outputStream to do it. Will delete this question.

Comment: @AleksandrM I posted a slightly different question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438657/jasper-reports-not-displaying-pdf-on-browser-shows-no-error-on-console) . Could you please look into it?