# Jasper Reports not displaying pdf on browser, shows no error on console

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

This is a snippet of my Java class code

**Case 1**

```
    request=ServletActionContext.getRequest();
            response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
            if(response!=null)
                System.out.println("Response is not null");
            System.out.println("coming to this method");
            inputStream= this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/ram/report/jasper/Report.jrxml");
            JasperReport jasperReport=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
            HashMap<String, Object> params = null;

            JasperPrint jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
            JRExporter exporter = new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, new File("").getAbsolutePath()+"/UserReport.pdf");
            exporter.exportReport();
            File file = new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath()+"/UserReport.pdf"); 

            inputStream  = new FileInputStream(file);
            response.flushBuffer();
            System.out.println("Made report");
            return "ajaxReturn";
        }
```

**Case 2**

```
request=ServletActionContext.getRequest();
                response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
                if(response!=null)
                    System.out.println("Response is not null");
                System.out.println("coming to this method");
                inputStream= this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/ram/report/jasper/Report.jrxml");
                JasperReport jasperReport=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
                HashMap<String, Object> params = null;

                JasperPrint jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
                JRExporter exporter = new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter();
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, new File("").getAbsolutePath()+"/UserReport.pdf");
                exporter.exportReport();
                File file = new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath()+"/UserReport.pdf"); 

                inputStream  = new FileInputStream(file);
                ServletOutputStream op = response.getOutputStream();
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                        "application; filename=\"" + "UserReport.pdf");
                byte[] bbuf = new byte[50000];
                int length=0;
                while ((inputStream != null) && ((length = inputStream.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
                    op.write(bbuf, 0, length);
                }
                op.flush();
                op.close(); 
                response.flushBuffer();
                System.out.println("Made report");
                return "ajaxReturn";
            }
```

This is my action

```
<action name="reportData" class="Reportfetchnew">
<interceptor-ref name="cookie"></interceptor-ref>
 <interceptor-ref name="cookieProvider"></interceptor-ref>
 <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
<result name="success">htdocs/jsp/report_new/report_tool.jsp</result>
 <result name="ajaxReturn" type="stream" >
    <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
    <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="UserReport.pdf"</param>
    <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>

    </result>
```

The problem I am facing is that the pdf is not displayed on the browser **at all** despite showing no error on the Eclipse console. 
After checking a few links, I thought of mirroring into an outputStream, so I did Case 2. However it gave the same identical result.Moreover, **"Made report"** is also being printed, meaning that the file has been created in **both cases**. So what exactly is the error here?

Comment: `ajaxReturn` -> Are you calling this action from ajax? What's the point?

Comment: I am giving an ajax call from my jsp to the java class. The Java class takes care of the report generation and returns "ajaxReturn" when success.

Comment: Just call your action **not** from ajax.

Comment: @AleksandrM I couldn't understand,sir..Please could you explain? Like I am having a input date range and a button . When I click the button, I need the report. Why can't I use ajax?

Comment: The primary reason for the ajax call was to try adding a table of the report. But right now, I am stuck in the pdf generation part itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)